# How to capture the user select text event in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom-events

I want to catch the event when the user select a text in Firefox page like IDM add-on (or IE8+) show a button when user select text.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: A first solution would be to listen to the `mouseup` event and check whether the user has selected some text.

Answer (score 3):

You could attach a `mouseup` event listener and a `keypress` listener respectively for mouse and keyboard selections, and then use [`window.getSelection()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getSelection) to tell if any text is selected.

Comment: IE has no `window.getSelection()`, and selections may also be made using the keyboard.

Comment: @Tim Down: tqwer was asking specifically for Firefox… for keyboard selections could add `keypress` listener, or just attach a timeout to check periodically. Currently there are no listeners specifically for text select or clipboard changes.

Comment: The user also mentions "IE8+". And yes, I'm aware that there's no event that does this, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @Tim Down: he use "IE8+" only to show that he wants to monitor select actions as IE8+, and the IDM add-on do. He wants to have it in Firefox as the title mentions.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat surprisingly, there's no simple way to do this. IE has a `select` event that is implemented on all elements but other browsers have never extended this beyond inputs. You'll have to handle `keyup` and `mouseup` events for the whole document, and write some code to compare the current selection with the previous selection from when the event handler last ran.